# List of finitely presented groups with undecidable word problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, big-list, computability-theory, decidability

Is there any reasonably updated list of (representative) examples of finitely presented groups with undecidable word problem?

By "representative" I mean "avoiding obvious redundancy", i.e. examples different from each other in providing (from some point of view) new insight into the problem.

A brief comment on the ideas and methods used, and even the concrete presentations when possible, would also be of interest.

In case there is not such list, I wonder if it is a suitable big-list for MO.

Comment: Miller III (1981, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.7758&rep=rep1&type=pdf) produced f.p. groups with no nontrivial quotient has decidable word problem (DWP). (In comparison, recall that any f.p. simple group has DWP.) Paul Schupp told me once that Miller's paper contains ideas that are really subtle from the point of view of computability theory (having in mind that most undecidability results in group theory just consist in just encoding some undecidability feature and contain no original idea from the point of view of computability).

Comment: Take a look at the reference here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107357/group-presentations-with-few-relations-and-undecidable-word-problem?rq=1 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84398/economical-hard-word-problem and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups#Examples

Comment: Thank you for the references. Perhaps there are not enough examples for a big-list. Miller's paper looks interesting anyway.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Miller's book cited above you can look at ["Algorithmic problems in varieties"](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/%7Emsapir/ftp/pub/survey/survey.ps) and ["Asymptotic invariants, complexity of groups and related problems"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1325) for more recent examples. These include  results about  complexity of the word problem. Even more recent results are in papers by Olshanskii and myself (see the arXiv).